# Smoothness of the squared distance to the boundary of an open subset

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

If $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $U$ a regular domain (i.e. $U$ is an open subset and $\partial U$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$), is the function $d( \cdot, \partial U)^2 : U \to \Bbb R$ smooth?

Without the square, I believe that it is smooth almost everywhere (it is Lipschitz, in fact), but is the square sufficient to iron out the singularities of $d( \cdot, \partial U)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Consider the case in which $U$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $d(x,\partial U)^2 = (1-|x|)^2$, which is not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: You gotta love when a serious question comes up, you think for a while it may be correct, and then the counterexample is the simplest possible one. :-)

Comment: @JackLee: I'm not liking it. Anyway, I'm investigating whether $\Delta d(\cdot , \partial U)$ can be given a meaning as a function (i.e. not as a distribution). Since $d(\cdot , \partial U)$ is Lipschitz, $\nabla d(\cdot , \partial U)$ exists almost everywhere. How could I deal with an extra layer of derivatives, though, to get from $\nabla$ to $\Delta$?

Comment: @AlexM.: That would be a good thing to pose as a separate question.